# c# SQL stored procedure Id issue

Tags: c#, sql, bulk

My stored procedure is not working like I tought it would, can't figure out how to fix it. Using SQL server management studio 2008

This is where the values get stored:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Events].[dbo].[Fouten] where TreinId = 1338
```

However the '1338' is a name of a field inside the Treinen table that is linked with a TreinId to the Fouten table. for example: TreinId = 136, Name = '1338'

So I'm trying to insert the name field and retrieve the Id from the other table so that i  can have my results in:

```
SELECT *
      FROM [Events].[dbo].[Fouten] where TreinId = 136
```

The stored procedure (microsoft sql manager 2008):

```
USE [Events]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_BatchInsert]    Script Date: 03/15/2016 11:58:45 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_BatchInsert] (@Datum date, @Foutcode varchar(8), @Omschrijving varchar(50), @Module varchar(20), @Time time(3), @Teller int, @Mnemo varchar(9), @treinNaam varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN
            INSERT INTO dbo.Fouten (Datum,FoutCode,Omschrijving,Module,Time,Teller,Mnemo,TreinId) VALUES (@Datum,@Foutcode,@Omschrijving,@Module,@Time,@Teller,@Mnemo,(SELECT TreinId from [Events].[dbo].[Treinen] WHERE Name = @treinNaam));
END
```

[image]

c# code:

```
public void BatchBulkCopy(string rapport)
        {
            // Get the DataTable 
            DataTable dtInsertRows = TextReader(rapport);

            using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(GetConnectionString(), SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints))
            {
                sbc.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Fouten";
                sbc.BatchSize = 8000;


                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Datum", "Datum");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Foutcode", "FoutCode");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Omschrijving", "Omschrijving");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Module", "Module");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Time", "Time");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Teller", "Teller");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("Mnemo", "Mnemo");
                sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("treinNaam", "TreinId");

                sbc.NotifyAfter = dtInsertRows.Rows.Count;
                sbc.SqlRowsCopied += new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(sbc_SqlRowsCopied);

                try
                {
                    sbc.WriteToServer(dtInsertRows);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
                sbc.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a simple `join`.

Comment: Tag dbms used. (That sp code is product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a `SELECT` to feed into the `INSERT` statements, rather than trying to force it into the `VALUES` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Fouten 
(Datum,FoutCode,Omschrijving,Module,Time,Teller,Mnemo,TreinId)
SELECT
    @Datum,
    @Foutcode,
    @Omschrijving,
    @Module,
    @Time,
    @Teller,
    @Mnemo,
    TreinId from [Events].[dbo].[Treinen]
WHERE
    Name = @treinNaam;
```

If your RDBMS has a function to retrieve the latest inserted autoincrement number for a table then it becomes even easier.

Comment: It's still using the Name as the TreinId, Instead of using the TreinId matching to the Name :( Maybe it because of this part? sbc.ColumnMappings.Add("treinNaam", "TreinId");

Comment: Well, umm, yeah... if you put the value of the name into the ID parameter then that's going to be a problem.